# How do I keep a previous value in a textbox when using a checkbox to add information to the textbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox

Okay, so I created this form that I use for work and it works pretty well considering my skill level is most definitely not professional. I learned HTML and JavaScript for a couple years in high school and have been self-taught on a lot of things since. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have my form set up so that if I select an item from a drop-down menu and click a checkbox, the canned response I created is generated in the textbox. However, if I wrote anything in the textbox in advance, it gets wiped out. Now, the way I learned how to do this was based off of self-taught stuff I found online, so this is an example of what I have for the function that gets my canned responses:

```
function FillDetails29(f) {
  if(f.checkbox29.checked == true) {
    f.TEXT.value = ('' + f.trans.value + '')
} else {
    f.TEXT.value = "";
      }
}
```

I know that having

```
} else {
   f.TEXT.value = "";
```

is going to wipe out anything that was there before or after if I uncheck the checkbox.

My question is what should I be doing to maintain my previous value when I uncheck the box? Example being:

Previous value to using the checkbox: Andrea looked good in that sweater.

Using the checkbox: Andrea looked good in that sweater. I wonder if there are any more at the store?

Unchecking the checkbox: Andrea looked good in that sweater.

I've done a lot of searching to see if there's something out there that can solve my problem but I'm afraid I'm not phrasing it right when I google it. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction for this? I know that you guys don't want to just solve it for me and that I should be able to present some kind of example of what I've done to fix the problem but I've tried so many things that haven't worked that it would take too long to list them all without causing some kind of confusion. Even if you just have a website that you know of with an example of this that you can provide me, I'd be very grateful. Thank you!

**Edit 1:** To clarify, my original setup actually contains 3 forms. One form is for data entry where I input caller information and the checkbox for that spits out the entered data into a singular line of details for when I copy and paste into another program.

The second form is where I have quite a few checkboxes that I use because each section of the form requires separate canned responses. I work for a health insurance company on the phones with doctors offices (and soon I'll be talking to members as well) and I created the form to shorten the amount of time it takes for me to document information. So I have checkboxes that generate data for specific benefits, eligibility, authorizations, transferring the call, etc.

I have a lot of checkboxes to contend with. About 32, by my count. More, if I need to add them. Most of these checkboxes are connected with drop-down menus with the necessary canned response for it. Some of them are connected to their own textbox where I need to enter some kind of pre-determined data, such as a date of birth or a doctor's name. Those are not the focus, though. Once I enter data or select an option from the drop-down and click the corresponding checkbox, the data from that selected option appears in a main text area so that I can copy and paste the response to the work program.

The third form is one that's generated for claims information and has 10 checkboxes on it.

So, if you require more examples of what I'm referring to, I can provide them but it will take a few minutes for me to scrub the work related data that out of the canned responses I created.

**Edit 2:** The response I got from Epascarello was extremely helpful and I've been trying to experiment with different ways to keep the previous value at the start of the new text being inserted from the checkbox with no luck in getting what I'm looking for, though something unexpected has happened when I start with an empty box and select an option after I altered the code he suggested to this:

```
function FillDetails29(f) {
  const elem = f.TEXT;
  if (!elem.dataset.prevValue) elem.dataset.prevValue = elem.value;
  const updatedValue = f.checkbox29.checked ? f.trans.value : (elem.dataset.prevValue || '') + (f.trans.value);
  elem.value = updatedValue;
}
```

What started to happen is that if the box was blank previously and I selected an option, the option would generate. Then, if I unchecked the box, the option would remain. If I selected a new option, the new option generates. If I then unchecked the box, the first option *and* the second option would be there.

Example:

First option selected: Andrea looked great in that sweater.

Second option selected: I wonder if it's on sale now?

When unchecked, first option remains until second option is checked. When second option is unchecked, this is what results (from the same drop-down and checkbox): Andrea looked great in that sweater. I wonder if it's on sale now?

Now, I added the same kind of element to another checkbox item in the same area resulting in the code looking like this for that section:

```
function FillDetails28(f) {
  const elem = f.TEXT;
  if (!elem.dataset.prevValue) elem.dataset.prevValue = elem.value;
  const updatedValue = f.checkbox28.checked ? f.dental.value : (elem.dataset.prevValue || '') + (f.dental.value);
  elem.value = updatedValue;
}

 function FillDetails29(f) {
  const elem = f.TEXT;
  if (!elem.dataset.prevValue) elem.dataset.prevValue = elem.value;
  const updatedValue = f.checkbox29.checked ? f.trans.value : (elem.dataset.prevValue || '') + (f.trans.value);
  elem.value = updatedValue;
}
```

And if I do something similar there, checking box 28 and then checking box 29, only whatever was most recently checked will materialize there. ***However,*** once everything is unchecked, *each selected option will appear in the text box.*

Example:

Checkbox 28 selected: Steven doesn't look good today.

Text area shows: Steven doesn't look good today.

Checkbox 29 selected: Andrea looks good in that sweater.

Text area shows: Andrea looks good in that sweater.

Checkbox 28 unselected with 29 still selected, text area shows: Steven doesn't look good today. Steven doesn't look good today.

Checkbox 28 and 29 now unselected, text area shows: Steven doesn't look good today. Andrea looks good in that sweater.

How should I be fashioning this so that those two options materialize one after another when the boxes are checked rather than when they're unchecked?

Comment: Do you have 29 different functions for checkboxes?

Comment: might need to see the rest of your code, only the ones relevant to your question

Comment: Oh, boy. Well, my form actually has quite a few checkboxes that are used to fill in the text box and I'm in the process of merging 3 separate forms into one comprehensive form. So, I can try to give you guys a more comprehensive look at my coding but it's really messy to look at in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value into a data variable and reference it.

```js
function FillDetails29(f) {
  const elem = f.TEXT;
  if (!elem.dataset.prevValue) elem.dataset.prevValue = elem.value;
  const updatedValue = f.checkbox29.checked ? f.trans.value : (elem.dataset.prevValue || '');
  elem.value = updatedValue;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that definitely fixes one part of my issue, so thank you for that! Where can I find the resource that helps with that online or in a book so I can better study it?

When I add that code to replace my original, it retains the original typed value when I uncheck the box but it doesn't place the canned response after it. What should I be doing or what resource should I look to for doing that?

Comment: Okay, after some researching and retooling, I got the form to do exactly what I want, plus a few extra things that I wasn't expecting. Thanks so much for the help everyone!! You guys rock!